# How can i remove these special characters from JSON output file

Tags: linux, shell

^[[0;32m ?~V? ^[[0m

JSON file is being written by shell script.

So the text processing produces these special characters, tried using dos2unix and changing the characters globally using %s option as well.

Comment: Can't you just fix the script that produces the JSON file?

Comment: @melpomene these hidden characters are being displayed after generating JSON output n during validation, so could not find during run time to fix it.

Comment: What do you mean, "during validation"? What validation?

Comment: I guess these are [ANSI escape sequences](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html) generated by a component of your shell script. If we have more details about your shell script we might help you to supress such characters, which is alwys the better solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. I introduced some control characters in a sample JSON file which can be displayed using "cat -v" command. Those with ^B,^A,^D are control characters.
Use perl to remove the control characters completely. You can redirect to a new file

```
> cat -v json_control.txt

^B{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": ^B{
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}^D
^A


>  perl -pe ' { s/[\x00-\x09\x0B-\x1F]//g } ' json_control.txt | cat -v

{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}

>
```